# How to modify the template of a new file?

Tags: pycharm

When I create a new Python file, it is automatically filled in with one line

```
__author__ = '<mynamehere>'
```

where `<mynamehere>` is my identity as seen by Pycharm

Where can i modify this template to add more useful information? (starting with `# coding=utf-8`)?

I looked within the files of my Pycharm installation but `__author__` was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is configurable](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/file-and-code-templates-2.html?search=template) at `File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates | Python Script`

[image]

Despite the mention of `For current project`, the setting is applied system-wide (you find it again by going through the same path in `Default settings` instead of `Settings`.